# Delete lines which contain only + signs

Tags: notepad++, regex

I am trying to convert my html document to asciidoc. But result lines have weird + signs like these:

```
++

+
Mandatory Relationship
+


* *many-to-many* – because databases don’t support this kind of
relationship, it is physically implemented via a *third junction table*
using *one-to-many* relationships.
+

+
```

I want to delete these lines using notepad++ regex.
I tried the following:

```
^+$
```

^ and $ are anchors specifying the beginning & end of the line and I put + sign between them.But this regex doesn't work. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: `+` is a special character (repeat previous one or more times), so you need to escape it by searching for `^\+$`.

Comment: Thanks but this regex doesn't delete lines which contain +++,++++.I tried ^.*\+$ but this regex deletes some contents of the file which contains + sign.

Comment: Your question is confusing - the title is **delete lines which contains only + sign**, which is what I addressed. To match multiple `+` signs, you also need the special meaning of `+`, so search for `^\++$`.

Comment: (I've corrected your title.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the regex you're looking for is

```
^\++$
```

The `\+` escapes the `+` sign, and the second plus searches for one or more occurence

EDIT:
saw it after posting, [Delete lines which contain only + signs](https://superuser.com/questions/1372487/delete-lines-which-contain-only-signs#comment2066573_1372487) already answered in comments